# how to send data to database with vue.js (ajax)

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

i'm looking for a tutorial for vue.js where can i send data to database with ajax. I find few examples but there is no explanation. Can somebody write a example and explain it, please? Between, i'm using laravel, can i send data to a controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Laravel, I start by creating a Laravel controller that will handle all the ajax requests (AjaxController.php) doing validations and interacting with the database, normal stuff. It doesn't have to be a dedicated controller though, you can use any controller, I just do it like that to keep things organized to me. In the client side, I declare a method in my vue app or component (depending on the project it can make more sense do it in a more global way or keep it just in some component) to which I pass the data that I want to send to the server. There you can use whatever you want to do the ajax request, pure javascript, jquery or even vue-resource as pointed in the previous answer. I usually use jquery because I happen to have in all of my projects and I'm more familiarized with the syntax but it's really up to you. Here's how I do it,

Laravel controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class AjaxController extends Controller
{

    public function createUser()
    {
        $data = request('data');

        $user = User::create($data);

        return 'ok';
    }    
}
```

Vue app:

```
var app = new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data: {
                name: '',
                age: '',
                country: ''
            },
            methods: {
                sendViaAjax: function(){
                    var data = {
                        '_token': yourCrsfToken,
                        'name': this.name,
                        'age': this.age,
                        'country': this.country 
                    };
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '/your-url',
                        method: 'POST',
                        data: data,
                        success: function(){

                            console.log('We did succeed!');
                        },
                        error: function(){
                            console.log('We did not succeed!');
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
});
```

and the html:

```
<div id='app'>
    <label for="user-name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="user-name" v-model="name" value="@{{ name }}">
    <label for="user-age">Age</label>
    <input type="text" id="user-age" v-model="age" value="@{{ age }}">
    <label for="user-country">Country</label>
    <input type="text" id="user-country" v-model="country" value="@{{ country }}">
</div>
```

I didn't test this example I just wrote it so don't be surprised if you find any error, but I hope it passed the general idea.

Cheers

Comment: Thank you man, but can you explain how to route that data to the Controller?

Comment: You create a route like any other in laravel. For the example that I gave you can simply have this in your routes.php:
`Route::post('your-url', [
            'as'   => 'any-alias',
            'uses' => 'AjaxController@createUser'
        ]);`

Answer (score 0):

You have to install `vue-resource` then you do:

```
this.$http.post('your/endpoint.php', {some: data}).then(response => {
  // something to do with your response
}
```

Comment: what is your/endpoint.php?

Comment: It's your endpoint.